# learning curve error with grid search

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle

I have this error running the following code. The culprit seems to be the line of code "`sp_randint(1, sqrt(X.shape[1]))`". If I replace it with a list object, then it seems fine. does anyone have any idea of this error?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.grid_search import RandomizedSearchCV

print sklearn.__version__

digits = load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,  random_state=9)
# specify parameters and distributions to sample from
param_dist = {"max_depth": [3, 5, 7, 9, None],
                       "min_samples_split": sp_randint(1, sqrt(X.shape[1])),
                       "bootstrap": [True, False]}
# run randomized search
n_iter_search = 2
n_cores = 2
cv = 3
random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=forest,
                                   param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   # scoring='roc_auc',
                                   cv=cv,
                                   n_iter=n_iter_search,
                                   n_jobs=1,
                                   random_state=9)
train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 2)
train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(random_search, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_cores, train_sizes=train_sizes)
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/Users/zech/env/tmp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/pool.py", line 372, in send
    CustomizablePickler(buffer, self._reducers).dump(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 396, in save_reduce
    save(cls)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: it's not found as __builtin__.instancemethod
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I would grid-search for each number of samples separately, but it should definitely be possible. Can you open an issue? For a discrete distribution as here, replacing it with a list is fine btw. Only for continuous distributions it really makes a difference.

Comment: @AndreasMueller: thanks for reply. I see pros and cons of grid-search or just using random/default model parameters. I'll open a ticket on github.

Comment: I meant if you replace it by a list, it will do exactly the same thing for a discrete distribution with finite support, as you did here. Still it needs to be fixed.